# How to find adjoint of this operator?

Tags: functional-analysis

For this matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
    2   & 3 \\
    1 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
 the operator is defined as $T_{x}$ = $(2x+3y ,x+4y)$. how can i find adjoint of this operator? any help would be appreciated thanx.

Comment: I am talking about the adjoint of the operator $T$ not the matrix

Comment: There is certainly a difference between the adjoint of an operator and of its matrix, but I don't feel like I understand the distinction you wish to draw here. Since you're in the standard basis, there in fact isn't one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the given matrix $A$ and $X=(x,y)^T$ so $T_X=AX$. Let $X'=(x',y')^T$ then

$$\langle AX,X'\rangle=(2x+3y)x'+(x+4y)y'=x(2x'+y')+y(3x'+4y')=\langle X,A'X'\rangle
$$
where $$A'=\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\3&4\end{pmatrix}=A^T$$
and the adjoint of $T_X$ is defined by $T^*_X=A^TX$.

Comment: thank u very much for the help

Answer (score 0):

The adjoint (in the modern use of the word) of an operator is its "conjugate-transpose" which is $T^\dagger(x,y) = (2x + y, 3x + 4y)$. This is because

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 4 \end{bmatrix}^\dagger = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}.$$